# OpenVZ (CentOS 7) no internet access while it worked before

Tags: centos7, openvz

Strange problem here ... I am using OpenVZ and have 3 containers. My setup worked fine for 3 years and yesterday something happend and i can't seem to find the issue on one container. The other 2 works as expected.

This is my openvz setup

```
[root@node1 ~]# vzlist -a
      CTID      NPROC STATUS    IP_ADDR         HOSTNAME
       101        133 running   67.212.65.43    serveur1.***.com
       102        139 running   67.212.65.44    serveur2.***.com
       103        187 running   67.212.65.45    serveur3.***.com
```

The faulty container is on 67.212.65.43
The other 2 is working fine
My provider told me everything is ok from there end for 67.212.65.43

```
[root@node1 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
67.212.65.44    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
67.212.65.45    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
67.212.65.46    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
67.212.65.43    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
67.212.65.40    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         67.212.65.41    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I can enter the faulty container by typing:

vzctl enter 101

This is what I tryed so fare:

```
[root@serveur1 /]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms

[root@serveur1 /]# traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
send: Operation not permitted

[root@serveur1 /]# nslookup 8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I tryed doing an iptables -F but that did not solve anything. the current rules is:

```
[root@serveur1 etc]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ALLOWIN (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ALLOWOUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DENYIN (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DENYOUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INVALID (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INVDROP (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain LOCALINPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain LOCALOUTPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain LOGDROPIN (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain LOGDROPOUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain cpanel-dovecot-solr (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-sshd (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I started checking my server network config ... But like I said, it worked fine for 3 years ... I am king of lost and need help finding the issue.

resolv.conf:

## Generated by NetworkManager

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

ifconfig

```
[root@serveur1 etc]# ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 60  bytes 4200 (4.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60  bytes 4200 (4.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

venet0: flags=211<UP,BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0  destination 127.0.0.1
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 45325  bytes 2970128 (2.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 51  bytes 14395 (14.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 2 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

venet0:0: flags=211<UP,BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet 67.212.65.43  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 67.212.65.43  destination 67.212.65.43
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
```

Everything seems to be set up right ... Let me know what extra info you need and i will post an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found how to solve this. After flushing the rules of the iptables i needed to recreate them like this:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -F FORWARD
```

After doing that, the server started responding again. Hope this helps if anybody gets that error in the future.